# Расчёт координат x и y каждой точки полёта снаряда в 3-мерной системе координат

Tags: python, математика, физика

Проблема заключается в расчёте x- и y-координат полёта точки. z работает верно. x и y горизонтальная плоскость а z вертикальная ось. При этом в консоли выводится каждое сообщение.

Вообще, хотелось бы настраивать параметр `initial_velocity`, а `degrees` -  сделать авторасчет угла от точки xyz0 до точки xyz1. При этом, при изменении этих двух параметров, точка xyz0 должны достигать xyz1.

```
import math
import time

x0, y0, z0 = 0, 0, 0 # Стартовая позиция
x1, y1, z1 = 10, 5, 15 # Конечная позиция

dx = x1 - x0
dy = y1 - y0
dz = z1 - z0

t = 0 # Текущее затраченное время
g = 9.81 # Гравитация
add_time = 0.1
degrees = 45 # Угол наклона с которого происходит выстрел. Он тут не используется но нужно его задействовать.
initial_velocity = 20 # Начальное ускорение
time_duration = math.sqrt((2 * dz) / g) # Затраченное время на полёт от x0, y0, z0 до x1, y1, z1
V0_z = g * time_duration
theta = math.atan2(dz, math.sqrt(dx ** 2 + dy ** 2))
current_x, current_y, current_z = x0, y0, z0

while t < time_duration:

    current_x = x0 + initial_velocity * math.cos(theta) * t + 0.5 * g * t ** 2 # Проблема тут
    current_y = y0 + initial_velocity * math.sin(theta) * t - 0.5 * g * t ** 2 # И тут
    current_z = z0 + V0_z * t - 0.5 * g * t ** 2
    
    print(f"Время: {t:.1f} сек, X: {current_x:.2f}, Y: {current_y:.2f}, Z: {current_z:.2f}")
    
    t += add_time
    time.sleep(add_time)
```

Это примерное изображение:

[image: Это примерное изображение]

@eri

```
import math

x0, y0, z0 = 0, 0, 0
x1, y1, z1 = 10, 5, 15

dx = x1 - x0
dy = y1 - y0
dz = z1 - z0

t = 0
g = 9.81
dt = 0.1
degrees = 45
v0 = 20
flight_time = math.sqrt((2 * dz) / g)

a = math.atan2(dx, dy)
dr = math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy)

k = degrees * math.pi / 180

v0r = v0 / math.tan(k)
v0z = v0 * math.tan(k)
v0x = v0r * math.tan(a)
v0y = v0r / math.tan(a)

while t < flight_time:
    z = z0 + v0z * t + g * t ** 2
    x = v0x * t
    y = v0y * t

    print(f"x: {x:.2f} y: {y:.2f} z: {z:.2f}")

    t += dt
```

Вот что получилось. Я что-то сделал не так тут что точка не достигает x1, y1, z1

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149165/discussion-on-question-by-pressf---x--y----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 2):

Начнем с дано

```
import math
import time

x0, y0, z0 = 0, 0, 0 # Стартовая позиция
x1, y1, z1 = 10, 5, 15 # Конечная позиция

dx = x1 - x0
dy = y1 - y0
dz = z1 - z0

t = 0 # Текущее затраченное время
g = 9.81 # Гравитация
dt = 0.1
v0 = 20 # Начальная скорость
```

Так как ускорения по x,y нет, то можно перейти в цилиндрические координаты и задача сводится к плоской.

```
а = math.atan2(dx, dy) # азимут 
dr = math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy) # радиус на цилиндрических координатах
```

Далее задача решается в плоскости `zr`.

Чтоб отобразить на экране нужно знать угол элевации ( или зенит  `э = math.pi/2 - з`). Допустим э=45

```
э = 45 * math.pi / 180

v0r = v0 / math.tan(э)
v0z = v0 * math.tan(э)
v0x = v0r * math.tan(а)
v0y = v0r / math.tan(а)

z = z0 + v0z * t + g * t**2
x = v0x * t
y = v0y * t
```

Попадание в точку не возможно, нужно задать какое-то минимальное расстояние.
Например перебирай t пока расстояние сокращается, запоминаешь последнюю точку. Между этой точкой и следующей время делишь пополам пока расстояние меджу точками не будет меньше расстояния до цели. Если при этом растояние до цели меньше заданной погрешности - значит попал.

## Для того чтоб попасть точно.

Элевация или скорость ( одно из этого нужно зафиксировать) начального направления считается из системы уравнений. Заодно подсчитывается время подлёта.

```
v0**2 = v0r**2 + v0z**2       #1
dz = v0z * t + g * t**2       #2
dr = v0r * t                  #3

э = math.atan2(v0z, v0r)
```

Тут простенькое уравнение 4ой степени, сводится к квадратному по t.
Если начальной скорости достаточно, то будет 1 или 2 действительных корня. Если корней нет - добавляйте начальной скорости.

Решать подстановкой 2 и 3 в 1

```
tt = t**2
(dz+dr)**2 - (2*g *dz + v0**2 ) * tt + g**2 * tt**2 = 0
```